# How can I use initState in a widget build to reference the value of riverpod?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I want to assign the value of currentUser.profilepictureURL to ListImage.
But if I put the initState outside of the widget build, it will be out of scope. Please tell me.

```
    class _MyHomePageState extends ConsumerState<MyHomePage> {
  var listImage = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final currentUser = ref.watch(userModelProvider);
    void initState() {
      listImage.add(currentUser.profilePictureURL);
      super.initState();
    }
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using consumerWidget? Can you include full widget

Comment: I use consumerWidget. I am sorry for posting a code that is difficult to understand. Thanks to the other person's answer, it was solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your are using initState is wrong. InitState is an `@override` and it should not to be used inside a build method.

try this:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends ConsumerState<MyHomePage> {
  var listImage = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final currentUser = ref.watch(userModelProvider);
    listImage.add(currentUser.profilePictureURL);
    return Container();
  }
}
```